# Regexp, I want to extract all the characters including dot(.) that are located between pre selected words

Tags: regex, matlab

```
a = regexp(textfile,'apple(\w*)orange','tokens')
```

I want to extract all the characters between the words apple and orange in text file. One example is;

orangeSEM_DAIM_244.25orange, however when I use may code I got nothing.

I try without the orange so this time I got SEM_DAIM_244 I guess there is a problem with dot(.) configuration. I cant add . to include the dot because when I do it creates problem for the some other words that doesn't includes dot but lies between apple and orange for example SEM_DAIM_A

PS: I am using MATLAB : )

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaround assertions to match `apple` or `orange` before and after your word, because they are lookarounds and not part of the matching string they will not be included in the matched tokens

```
((?<=apple)|(?<=orange)).*((?=apple)|(?=orange))
```

This pattern would match `SEM_DAIM_244.25` in all 4 cases

```
orangeSEM_DAIM_244.25orange
orangeSEM_DAIM_244.25apple
appleSEM_DAIM_244.25orange
appleSEM_DAIM_244.25apple
```